# My first program that wont run as expected. When I place in all the variables it straight goes to the else statement when it was correctly used

Tags: java, user-interface, if-statement, debugging

So, when I run my code, it won't run as expected.

My program asks you to enter 10 questions than 10 answers to go be quizzed on. When I enter the correct answer when I'm getting quizzed on, it will pop up to the else statement. Yes, I am aware that this CODE is really messy and using if and else statements make my code horrible. It is spaghetti code and I KNOW ill soon hopefully fix it later.

```
package com.ez.ez;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Quiz{
    public static void main (String[] args) {


        System.out.println("Welcome to my quiz program!");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Would you like to create a key?");
        String yesKeyOrNoKey = scanner.nextLine();
        if (yesKeyOrNoKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") || yesKeyOrNoKey.equalsIgnoreCase("True")) {
            System.out.println("Welcome! simply enter the QUESTIONS below, (They're 10 questions must be completed to run normal!))");

            System.out.println("What is your first question?");
            String firstQuestion = scanner.nextLine();


            System.out.println("What is your second question?");
            String secondQuestion = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your third question?");
            String thirdQuestion = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your fourth question?");
            String fourthdQuestion = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your fifth question?");
            String fifthQuestion = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your sixth question?");
            String sixthQuestion = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your seventh question?");
            String seventhQuestion = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your eigth question?");
            String eigthQuestion = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your ninth question?");
            String ninthQuestion = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("What is your tenth question?");
            String tenthQuestion = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println();

            System.out.println("Enter answer one");
            String answerOne = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter answer two");
            String answerTwo = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter answer three");
            String answerThree = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter answer four");
            String answerFour = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter answer five");
            String answerFive = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter answer six");
            String answerSix = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter answer seven");
            String answerSeven = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter answer eight");
            String answerEight = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter answer nine");
            String answerNine = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter answer ten");
            String answerTen = scanner.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Are you ready? to start your quiz!?");
            String readyKey = scanner.nextLine();
            if(readyKey.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes") || readyKey.equalsIgnoreCase("TRUE")) {
                System.out.println("AMAZING!");
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(firstQuestion);
                String yourAnswerOne = scanner.nextLine();

                if (yourAnswerOne == answerOne) {
                    System.out.println("Congrats! you made it passed level 1! 1/10 ");
                    System.out.println(secondQuestion);
                    String yourAnswerTwo = scanner.nextLine();
                    if(yourAnswerTwo == answerTwo) {
                        System.out.println("Congrats you had made it passed level 2! 2/10");
                        System.out.println(thirdQuestion);
                        String yourAnswerThree = scanner.nextLine();
                        if(yourAnswerThree == answerThree) {
                            System.out.println("Suprisingly did not fail third round! congrats! 3/10");
                            System.out.println(fourthdQuestion);
                            String yourAnswerFour = scanner.nextLine();
                            if(yourAnswerFour == answerFour) {
                                System.out.println("Amazing! your not done buddy 4/10 you can do it");
                                System.out.println(fifthQuestion);
                                String yourAnswerFive = scanner.nextLine();
                                if(yourAnswerFive == answerFive) {
                                    System.out.println("Half way done! keep it up!");
                                    System.out.println(sixthQuestion);
                                    String yourAnswerSix = scanner.nextLine();
                                    if(yourAnswerSix == answerSix) {
                                        System.out.println("Congrats 4 more to go!");
                                        System.out.println(seventhQuestion);
                                        String yourAnswerSeven = scanner.nextLine();
                                        if(yourAnswerSeven == answerSeven) {
                                            System.out.println("Congrats 7/10! 3 more to go" );
                                            System.out.println(eigthQuestion);
                                            String yourAnswerEight = scanner.nextLine();
                                            if( yourAnswerEight == answerEight) {
                                                System.out.println("2 more up and your set to go! 8/10");
                                                System.out.println(ninthQuestion);
                                                String yourAnswerNine = scanner.nextLine();
                                                if(yourAnswerNine == answerNine) {
                                                    System.out.println("ONE MORE!! YOUR SO CLOSE!");
                                                    System.out.println(tenthQuestion);
                                                    String yourAnswerTen = scanner.nextLine();
                                                    if(yourAnswerTen == answerTen) {
                                                        System.out.println("CONGRATS YOU HAD MADE IT GOOD JOB!!!");
                                                    } else {
                                                        System.out.println("Unfortunate lol ");
                                                    }
                                                } else {
                                                    System.out.println("NOOOO sad to see ya go Try again and maybe you can win!!");
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                System.out.println("YOU WERE SO CLOSE! try again and you may go up!");
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            System.out.println("So close! only if you made it up a notch!");
                                        }
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("Maybe if you tried hard enough you coudve done better! good luck");
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    System.out.println("Thats a 50%, are you happy with that? 5/10");
                                }
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Meh, close enough 4/10");
                            }


                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Sad to see you go bud");
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Booohooo you did not make it that far!");
                    }

                } else {
                    System.out.println("Sad to see you go! at the first level! 1/10");
                }


            }


        }  

    }
}
```

Comment: Ignoring the fact that there is no reason to nest those `if` blocks like that... we compare Strings in java with `.equals()`, not `==`.

Comment: It's odd you should encounter this issue, since earlier in your code you do use the equalsIgnore

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me fix it i forgot the basics in java